# Grouping records from list using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list with records that contains hours of work of workers by week but separed in days.

```
List<Hours> listHours = new List<Hours>();
```

Where my class is:

```
public class Hours
{
    private int week;
    private DateTime day;
    private int idEmployee;
    private decimal amount;
    private int numberDay;

    public  DateTime Day
    { get { return day; } set { day = value; } }
    public int IdEmployee
    { get { return idEmployee; } set { idEmployee = value; } }
    public int Week
    { get { return week; } set { week = value; } }
    public decimal Amount
    { get { return amount; } set { amount = value; } }

}
```

My listHours contain 4 records:

```
week     idemployee    day        numberday    amount
02        336        06/01/2014        1        8.5
02        336        07/01/2014        2        3.5
26        336        24/06/2014        2        8.5
26        336        25/06/2014        3        5.5
```

I need group the hours by week and employee Id and in the same record show amount for all week days like monday, tuesday...satruday and sunday.Like, 6th Jan 2014 is Monday, so 8.5 should be displayed otherwise zero.

**Sample Output:**

```
week      idEmployee        Mon    Tue    Wed    Thu    Fri    Sat    Sun
02          336             8.5    3.5     0       0      0      0    0
26          336              0     8.5    5.5      0      0      0    0
```

I need the equivalent in linq of next query:

```
select week, idemployee , sum(amount for number day1),0,0,0,0,0,0
from myList
group by week, idemployee
union
select week, idemployee , 0,sum(amount for number day2),0,0,0,0,0
from myList
group by week, idemployee
union
...
union
select week, idemployee , 0,0,0,0,0,0,sum(amount for number day7)
from myList
group by week, idemployee
```

Comment: Do you mean order rather than group and also what is your question?

Comment: @mjpl2012 It will help your question if you can provide sample code demonstrating what you have already tried, or the approach you have taken. This question doesn't even ask a question, it just implies one based on your requirements.

Comment: I´ve tryed to explain better what I need... I´m new with Linq but I suposse that last query could do it in a easy way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

**Steps Involved:-**
1. First step is simple as we need to group by Week & EmployeeId
2. This is a bit tricky, Since day of week ranges from 1-7, I have used a list using `Enumerable.Range` and applied a **left join** because we need all the weekdays even if no amount is present.

```
var result = items.GroupBy(x => new { x.Week, x.IdEmployee })
                  .Select(x => new
                           {
                              x.Key.Week,
                              x.Key.IdEmployee,
                              output = (from t in Enumerable.Range(1, 7)
                                        join w in x
                                        on t equals (int)w.Day.DayOfWeek into allitem
                                        from data in allitem.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                        select new 
                                        {
                                            Amount = data == null ? 0 : data.Amount
                                        }).ToList()
                          });
```

Where I have used following as input:-

```
 List<Hours> items = new List<Hours>
            {
                new Hours { Week = 2, IdEmployee=336,Day = new DateTime(2014,01,06),Amount = 8.5m },
                new Hours { Week = 2, IdEmployee=336,Day = new DateTime(2014,01,07),Amount = 3.5m },
                new Hours { Week = 26, IdEmployee=336,Day = new DateTime(2014,06,24),Amount = 8.5m },
                new Hours { Week = 26, IdEmployee=336,Day = new DateTime(2014,06,25),Amount = 5.5m }
            };
```

Then I simply printed the output on screen using:-

```
string[] days = { "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun" };
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Week:{0}\tEmployeeId:{1}", item.Week, item.IdEmployee);
                foreach (var x in item.output.Select((v,i) => new {v,i}))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}",days[x.i],x.v.Amount);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
```

Comment: @mjpl2012 - You are Welcome :) Just pay more attention while posting a question, Probably since you didn't posted your own code ppl voted as "Unclear". You can still leave a comment and ask to re-open the question for more answers :)